# Issues replacing meta-tags with a template of a template implementation

Tags: javascript, templates, jsrender

Am trying to get templates of templates working simply by obscuring the markup for data variable placeholders that I want to use in the resulting template ... something is wrong with my replace js code seems to skip tag begining replacements for some reason

```js
renderDoubleOrderTemplate = function renderDoubleOrderTemplate(secondOrderTemplate, options) {
            $.templates("secondOrderTemplate", secondOrderTemplate);
            var firstOrderTemplateMarkup = $.render.secondOrderTemplate(options);
            if (debug) console.log("firstOrderTemplateMarkup: " + firstOrderTemplateMarkup);
            var rNewLine = /[ \t]*(\r\n|\n|\r)/g;
            //remove new lines before meta template replace
            firstOrderTemplateMarkup = firstOrderTemplateMarkup.replace(rNewLine, "");
            firstOrderTemplateMarkup = firstOrderTemplateMarkup.replace("  ", " ");
            String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
                var target = this;
                return target.split(search).join(replacement);
            };

            var firstOrderTemplateString = firstOrderTemplateMarkup.replaceAll('[[@', '{{:');
            firstOrderTemplateString = firstOrderTemplateMarkup.replaceAll('[[|', '{{/');
            firstOrderTemplateString = firstOrderTemplateMarkup.replaceAll('[[', '{{');
            firstOrderTemplateString = firstOrderTemplateMarkup.replaceAll(']]', '}}');


            if (debug) console.log(firstOrderTemplateString);
            return firstOrderTemplateString
        },
```

BEFORE RUNNING THE CODE

```
{{for inputFieldArray}}
    <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-4 control-label" label-required="*">{{:fieldDisplyLabel}}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <li class="dropdown" style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="{{:type}}" class="adduser-input form-control" id="{{:name}}-input" name="{{:name}}" [[if currentInput.{{:name}}]] value=[[@currentInput.{{:name}}]][[|if]] autocomplete="off">
                <ul id="{{:name}}-input-sugggest" class="dropdown-menu" style="z-index:1000">
                    {{for suggestions}}
                    <li><a class="suggestion" id="firstName-{{#index}}" href="#">[[@{{:name}}]]</a></li>
                    {{/for}}
                </ul>
            </li>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/for}}
```

AFTER RUNNING THE ABOVE CODE ON THE SECOND ORDER (TEMPLATE OF A TEMPLATE) THE HTML LOOKS LIKE THIS WITH SOME CHARACTER SEQUENCES NOT REPLACED

```
<div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-4 control-label" label-required="*">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <li class="dropdown" style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="text" class="adduser-input form-control" id="firstName-input" name="firstName" [[if currentInput.firstName}} value=[[@currentInput.firstName}}[[|if}} autocomplete="off">
                <ul id="firstName-input-sugggest" class="dropdown-menu"
                    style="z-index:1000"> </ul>
            </li>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So am just wonddering what is wrong with my replace logic, obviously want to make the resulting rendered html string valid for jsrender so now that the template is created I can merge data to create the final rendering

Answer (score 0):

I didn't look closely at your code to find the bug... Rather I would recommend that you use the API feature *[$.views.settings.delimiters(...);](http://www.jsviews.com/#settings/delimiters)* to switch to and fro between alternate delimiters. That way, you won't need to write any string replacement code.

See the example: [Using alternative delimiters to 'render a template with a template'](http://www.jsviews.com/#settings/delimiters@tmpl-for-tmpl).

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found the following logic works ... there is no bug in my code maybe an oversight some little side effect that stops one from doing it that other way... thanks for your answer

```
  renderDoubleOrderTemplate = function renderDoubleOrderTemplate(secondOrderTemplate, options) {
        $.templates("secondOrderTemplate", secondOrderTemplate);
        var firstOrderTemplateMarkup = $.render.secondOrderTemplate(options);

        //remove new lines before meta template replace
        firstOrderTemplateMarkup = firstOrderTemplateMarkup.replace(/[ \t]*(\r\n|\n|\r)/g, "");
        firstOrderTemplateMarkup = firstOrderTemplateMarkup.replace("  ", " ");

        var firstOrderTemplateString = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < firstOrderTemplateMarkup.length; i = i + 1) {
            var replace = false;
            var char = firstOrderTemplateMarkup.charAt(i);
            if (char === '[' || char === ']') {
                if (char === '[') {
                    firstOrderTemplateString = firstOrderTemplateString.concat('{{');
                    replace = true;
                }
                if (char === ']') {
                    firstOrderTemplateString = firstOrderTemplateString.concat('}}');
                    replace = true;
                }

                var nextchar = firstOrderTemplateMarkup.charAt(i + 1);
                if (nextchar === '@' || nextchar === '|') {

                    if (nextchar === '@') {
                        firstOrderTemplateString = firstOrderTemplateString.concat(':');
                        replace = true;
                    }
                    if (nextchar === '|') {
                        firstOrderTemplateString = firstOrderTemplateString.concat('/');
                        replace = true;
                    }
                    i = i + 1; //skip to next
                }
            }
            if (replace === false) firstOrderTemplateString = firstOrderTemplateString.concat(char);
        }

        return firstOrderTemplateString
    },
```

but yeah avoiding replacement code seems to be the answer, wouldn't mind figuring out the js weirdness that stops the other way from working ... not today though